# How to insert header tags to API Json

Tags: laravel

Hello im making a `GET` api in laravel that shows values from database and im trying to make it that the returned json result to have a header tag an example is this public api

> https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

As you can see this api shows the `status:success` and then `data:`  , this is my code:

```
 function getDevice()
    {
        return Client::all();
    }
```

And this is the result i get in postman:

```
  data [  //here to have a header
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mr. Omari Schaefer DVM",
            "email": "kulas.julian@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "29",
            "salary": "150",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Hattie Brakus",
            "email": "deckow.coby@example.com",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "30",
            "salary": "565",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Sabrina Rosenbaum",
            "email": "kautzer.madison@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "31",
            "salary": "254",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Ms. Fiona Fritsch",
            "email": "juwan.damore@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "32",
            "salary": "029",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Michael Dooley",
            "email": "hayes.reinhold@example.org",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "33",
            "salary": "265",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Prof. Kelley Koepp Jr.",
            "email": "kutch.jessie@example.org",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "34",
            "salary": "688",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Herminia McClure PhD",
            "email": "ywillms@example.com",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "35",
            "salary": "103",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Morton Considine",
            "email": "lesly.pfeffer@example.com",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "36",
            "salary": "804",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Katlyn Muller",
            "email": "peter93@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "37",
            "salary": "695",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Wilber Stehr",
            "email": "bmckenzie@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "38",
            "salary": "941",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Test User",
            "email": "test@example.com",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "60",
            "salary": "448",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        }
    ]

What im trying to do is:

    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mr. Omari Schaefer DVM",
            "email": "kulas.julian@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "29",
            "salary": "150",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Hattie Brakus",
            "email": "deckow.coby@example.com",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "30",
            "salary": "565",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Sabrina Rosenbaum",
            "email": "kautzer.madison@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "31",
            "salary": "254",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Ms. Fiona Fritsch",
            "email": "juwan.damore@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "32",
            "salary": "029",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Michael Dooley",
            "email": "hayes.reinhold@example.org",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "33",
            "salary": "265",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Prof. Kelley Koepp Jr.",
            "email": "kutch.jessie@example.org",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "34",
            "salary": "688",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Herminia McClure PhD",
            "email": "ywillms@example.com",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "35",
            "salary": "103",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Morton Considine",
            "email": "lesly.pfeffer@example.com",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "36",
            "salary": "804",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Katlyn Muller",
            "email": "peter93@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "37",
            "salary": "695",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Wilber Stehr",
            "email": "bmckenzie@example.net",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "38",
            "salary": "941",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Test User",
            "email": "test@example.com",
            "phone_number": "0697830800",
            "age": "60",
            "salary": "448",
            "created_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-02-17T08:36:00.000000Z"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getDevice() 
{
 return ['data' => 
 Client::all(),
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below solution for every response :

return response()->json('status' => 'success','message' => 'Client listing successfully.','data' => Client::all());

If you know how to use the helper function in Laravel then Please used the below for all responses:

Example :

In Controller, Just add the below line :

```html
return  apiResponse('success','Client listed successfully',Client::all()]);
```

```html
if (!function_exists('apiResponse')) {
    function apiResponse($status = null, $message = null, $data = null, $code = 200, $extra = []) {
        $response = [
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
            'data' => $data,
        ];
        if(!empty($extra)){
            $response = array_merge($response,$extra);
        }
        return response()->json($response, $code);
    }
}
```

I think this will help you a lot.